# How to cache dotnet installation in GitHub Actions

Tags: .net, caching, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two steps in my CI pipeline. one is to cache the installation path of dotnet and the other is dotnet installation. and using windows-2019 image. but the system never recognizes that .net 7 is available it always has .net 6.0 installed. The cache also shows that 200MB is cached but maybe some PATH variable needs tweaking. Can someone help me with this?

```yaml
    runs-on: windows-2019

    env:
      DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR: '.\.dotnet'
      DOTNET_ROOT: '.\.dotnet'
```

My cache step is:

```yaml
      - name: Cache dotnet
        id: cache-dotnet-core # id used in cache-hit condition
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: '.\.dotnet' #~/.dotnet
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-${{ hashFiles('**/project.assets.json') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-${{ hashFiles('**/project.assets.json') }}
```

and my dotnet installation step is

```
      - name: Install Dotnet
        #if: steps.cache-dotnet-core.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' # condition to check if old installation is available in cache
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x
```

Remember once the cache is saved the 2nd run of the job will show you that .net 6.0 is installed whereas 7.0 should be there.

Here's the complete workflow:

```yaml
name: dotnet-pipeline
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    name: check-dotnet-version
    runs-on: windows-2019 # Win 10 IoT En is not available on github actions

    env:
      DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR: '.\.dotnet'
      DOTNET_ROOT: '.\.dotnet'

    steps:      
      # maintain cache of dotnet installation
      - name: Cache dotnet
        id: cache-dotnet-core
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: '.\.dotnet'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-7
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-7

      # dotnet will only be installed if the files are not found in cache
      - name: Install Dotnet
        if: steps.cache-dotnet-core.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' 
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x
          
      # validate version number
      - name: validate dotnet version
        run: 'dotnet --version'
```

Comment: Please combine the workflow in one code block. That'll be easier to copy/paste and reproduce. Also, please add the error that you're getting along with how it's been invoked. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem yes i understand. complete code is now added. and there is no error code just version should be .net 7 but it is showing .net 6. which means the cache is not working. since in the first run, the cache is not used and .net 7.0 is perfectly showing its version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution could be to use the absolute path to the `dotnet` executable where it is installed and cached i.e. by using the prefix `DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR` throughout for installation, caching, and wherever the `dotnet` command is invoked.

Alternatively, for using it without the prefix, `DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR` could be added to `GITHUB_PATH` before using the `dotnet` command i.e.:

```
echo "${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}" | Out-File -FilePath $ENV:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

Here's the complete workflow with `GITHUB_PATH` ([tested](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/workflows/ci-cache-dotnet.yml)):

```yaml
name: cache_dotnet

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2019

    env:
      DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR: '.\.dotnet'

    steps:
      - name: Cache dotnet
        id: cache-dotnet
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-7
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-dotnet-7

      - name: Install dotnet
        if: ${{ steps.cache-dotnet.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.0.x

      - name: Check default dotnet version
        run: dotnet --version

      - name: Set installed/cached dotnet path [${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}]
        run: echo "${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}" | Out-File -FilePath $ENV:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append

      - name: Check installed/cached dotnet version
        run: dotnet --version
```

**Output**

[image: Run]

See [Environment variables](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet#environment-variables) of the `actions/setup-dotnet` for more details.

---

Apart from that, from this [issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/issues/141), it looks like there was caching in the https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet action itself, and then it was disabled. You might want to keep track of this, just in case.

Comment: Here are the subsequent runs: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3974838152/jobs/6814343965 and https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3974846229/jobs/6814356924

Comment: so this is the trick ```run: ${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}\dotnet --version```. this means now whenever i need to build my code I always need to use the path of installation. thanks, @Azeem for the help.

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz: You're welcome! Yes, this is to make sure that the custom-installed and cached version is being used. Alternatively, you may set the `PATH` env var via `GITHUB_ENV` to make the cached version have the highest precedence.

Comment: I think the solution of the PATH variable will suit me. Does it work like this? 
```env:
 PATH: $PATH  ${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}```

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz: You'll have to prepend `${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}` to the existing `PATH` variable. I think this should work: `env: PATH: ${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }};%PATH%;`. Please test this on your side. I'll test this in a bit.

Comment: I had to use this ```run: '$Env:Path += ";${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}"'``` to update PATH variable. but still writing dotnet build doesn't uses the cache folder. so now I have updated my script to ```${{ env.DOTNET_INSTALL_DIR }}\dotnet build``` everywhere. not happy with this but its ok.

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz: Answer updated to add the path to `GITHUB_PATH`. You may verify the latest workflows here: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/workflows/ci-cache-dotnet.yml. Please test it on your side. Thanks!