# How to cache java installation using github actions pipeline

Tags: github, caching, github-actions, pipeline

I am installing JAVA with actions pipeline in github. To make faster the execution, I want to cache the java for next pipeline. The version I wanna use is 17 for JAVA. During first execution of pipeline, the specific version of java is installed correctly. When pipeline executed for 2nd time, the cached java is picked(Which I want too as well) but the it showing me the version 1.8 not 17. Can anyone help. Thanks

```
name: pipeline to install & cache java
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - do/cs # or the name of your main branch

  # manually run from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch: 
  
jobs:
  build:
    name: Install packeges 
    runs-on: windows-2019 # Win 10 IoT is not available on github actions

    steps:

      - name: Cache Java
        id: cache-java
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
         path: 'c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Microsoft_jdk\17.0.3\x64'
         key: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-17.0.3
         restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-17.0.3

      - name: Install Java
        if: ${{steps.cache-java.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'}} # condition to check if old installation is available in cache
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'microsoft'
          java-version: '17'
          architecture: 'x64'
         
      - name: Verify Java installation
        run: |
          echo "java version:"
          java -version
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cache dotnet installation in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180149/how-to-cache-dotnet-installation-in-github-actions)

Comment: Nope. This is not working for me. I follow the same procedure but didn't get my answer.

Comment: Please update your config in your question with what you tried according to the above thread. Thanks!

Comment: When I run the pipeline for 1st time, the java version is 17. For the 2nd time, it take cache version but instead of version 17, it shows me 1.8 version. I want it to take version 17 from cache as well. can you help me with this?

Comment: In the first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221475/how-to-cache-java-installation-using-github-actions-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment132736660_75221475), I shared the exact same problem with the `dotnet` caching. In this case, the same solution should work. Please go through that. update your config and test.

Comment: @Azeem yes, I follow that one, it is not working with me. Kindly do test with your system and let me know if it is working or not? thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75221475/edit) your question and your updated config under **UPDATE** section. I'll copy/paste that to test. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem I update it. Kindly do test. Thanks

Comment: I just checked the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75221475/revisions) and there's no change. You just removed the `name` which is needed. You  might want to fix that. Also, I just updated the above [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75193497/7670262) for the `GITHUB_PATH` alternative. Please check that before updating your question. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly write me an actions pipeline that caches the java using windows as an agent.

Comment: The pipeline I created is not picking the latest(17) version from cache. Kindly just solve this issue for me.

Comment: I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75237092/7670262) to a similar question with the complete workflow. You might want to check that and compare what's missing in your config. Good luck!