# How to cache Java installation using GitHub Actions

Tags: java, powershell, caching, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have created a GitHub actions script and in 2nd run, the cache step is used. However, the version that is cached was 17 but upon checking the version with `java -version` it shows version 1.8

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_352-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)
```

how do I do cache this particular version of java? thanks in advance.

my complete script.

```
name: dotnet-pipeline
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build-run-analysis
    runs-on: windows-2022
  
    env:
      JAVA_HOME: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Microsoft_jdk\17.0.3\x64'
      JAVA_HOME_17_X64: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Microsoft_jdk\17.0.3\x64'
     
    steps:  
    
      - name: Cache JDK
        id: cache-jdk
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.JAVA_HOME }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-17
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-
  
      # Install Java development kit using microsoft distro
      - name: Install Java
        if: steps.cache-jdk.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'microsoft'
          java-version: '17'
          check-latest: false # enforce to use files from cache
        
      - name: Set PATH
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.JAVA_HOME }}" | Out-File -FilePath $ENV:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append      


      - name: check version
        run: java -version
```

Comment: fwiw, the [hosted tool cache](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#Hosted-Tool-Cache) contains temurin LTS versions, so that comes bundled for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite similar to your earlier question about the `dotnet` caching:

- [How to cache dotnet installation in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180149/how-to-cache-dotnet-installation-in-github-actions)

---

The only thing is to cache the correct installed path and set it to `GITHUB_PATH` when the cache is hit.

`JAVA_HOME_17_X64` will be:

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Microsoft_jdk\17.0.3\x64
```

And, its `bin` subdirectory will be added to `GITHUB_PATH`:

```
${{ env.JAVA_HOME_17_X64 }}\bin
```

Here's the complete workflow:

```yaml
name: cache_java

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2022

    env:
      JAVA_HOME_17_X64: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Microsoft_jdk\17.0.3\x64'

    steps:
      - name: Cache JDK
        id: cache-jdk
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.JAVA_HOME_17_X64 }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-17
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-

      - name: Install Java
        if: ${{ steps.cache-jdk.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'microsoft'
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Check default Java version
        run: java -version

      - name: Set installed/cached Java path [${{ env.JAVA_HOME_17_X64 }}]
        run: echo "${{ env.JAVA_HOME_17_X64 }}\bin" | Out-File -FilePath $ENV:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append

      - name: Check installed/cached Java version
        run: java -version
```

Output:

[image: workflow run]

Comment: Yeah, it was the same as dotnet. but I was missing ```/bin```. I thought setting the home directory was just it as it was in the case of dotnet.

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz: `JAVA_HOME` contains JDK's main directory but the actual executables are under `$JAVA_HOME/bin` directory so that needed to be set.